# Deserializing a json file into a static class in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a static class with static fields and a json.

I can deserialize the json into a dynamic object, so I have all the fields and they match exactly the static fields in the class.

How can I use reflection to enumerate the fields and copy the values from the dynamic class into the static class fields?

I can't change the architecture, make it a singleton, etc; it's shared code and the class is going to remain static since it's globally shared settings object used by a shared library.

The solution needs to use reflection since the class evolves over time with new members. Otherwise I could have written a custom deserializer.

---

Adding more details, but there is really not much:

I have this static class:

```
static class A
{
    static int I;
    static string S;
}
```

and a json matching the fields exactly:

```
{
    "I" : 3,
    "S" : "hello"
}

var Data = JsonConvert.Deserialize<dynamic>(...);
```

I would like to initialize the static fields of class A with the values I deserialized from the json, into a dynamic object.

---

Another edit:

I came up with something similar to what David wrote, but this is less efficient since I use the deserializer to convert types, so David's solution is better.

here's what I came up with:

```
foreach (var Destination in typeof(Settings).GetProperties())
{
    var Name = Destination.Name;
    var T = Destination.PropertyType;
    var Value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("\"" + JT[Name] + "\"", T);
    Destination.SetValue(null, Value);
}
```

Comment: Show the code in a [mcve] so that we can get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: You don't need to use reflection directly, just use dynamic JSON parsing such as with `JToken.Parse`. Then manually assign the fields

Comment: I added more details

Comment: @Camilo, I can parse the json with the jtoken.parse method, but how do I cast each value to the type of the matching field in the static class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8074070/3254405

Comment: @numbtongue: I don't get the link with the question? even if the static fields are wrapped inside a class instance, the issue remains.

Comment: You can then desirialize JSON into array of outer objects and access the inner static class via constructor/methods, just an idea.. You trying to assign a list into single instance which may not be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this quite easily by having a matching non-static class, getting the properties of source and destination and looping through each one. For example, assuming we have two classes:

```
public static class A
{
    public static int I { get; set; }
    public static string S { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public string S { get; set; }
}
```

We can now do this:

```
public void MapToStaticClass(B source)
{
    var sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties();

    //Key thing here is to specify we want the static properties only
    var destinationProperties = typeof(A)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

    foreach (var prop in sourceProperties)
    {
        //Find matching property by name
        var destinationProp = destinationProperties
            .Single(p => p.Name == prop.Name);

        //Set the static property value
        destinationProp.SetValue(null, prop.GetValue(source));
    }
}
```

Another option is to deserialise to `JToken` and use that combined with reflection:

```
var source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);
```

And then:

```
public void MapJTokenToStaticClass(JToken source)
{
    var destinationProperties = typeof(A)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

    foreach (JProperty prop in source)
    {
        var destinationProp = destinationProperties
            .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(prop.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        var value = ((JValue)prop.Value).Value;

        //The ChangeType is required because JSON.Net will deserialise
        //numbers as long by default
        destinationProp.SetValue(null, Convert.ChangeType(value, destinationProp.PropertyType));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very specifically what I'm trying to avoid because fields in this class get added as the projects sharing the lib need; otherwise I would have written a custom deserializer and the problem would have been solved. But I need to come up with a reflection based method to accommodate changes I don't have control over.

Comment: I mentioned it needed to use reflection, but maybe I should have explained why. I'll edit the question

Comment: Yes, this answer uses reflection!

Comment: you're right, the question lacked clarity; hopefully this is fixed now.

Comment: Well, I added another option for you.

Comment: I came up with something similar, but yours is better. I'll mark yours as the answer and write what I came up with in the question. Thanks!

Comment: actually in the end, ChangeType is failing where the deserialization works because it can't convert types like TimeSpan, etc, but for the simple types, it's probably much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid intermediate (dynamic) class and read JSON directly to a static class, but complex code is needed:

```
var t = typeof(YourType);

var rdr = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader("{json text}"));
PropertyInfo pinf = null;
while (rdr.Read()) {
    if (rdr.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName) {
        pinf = t.GetProperty((string)rdr.Value);
    } else if (rdr.TokenType == JsonToken.String || rdr.TokenType == JsonToken.Boolean || rdr.TokenType == JsonToken.Date || 
                rdr.TokenType == JsonToken.Float || rdr.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer || rdr.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) {
        pinf.SetValue(null, rdr.Value);
    }
}
rdr.Close();
```